# Duplicating Values based on Series input

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a custom function that essentially extends replace functionality (with some domain specific concerns) Essentially I have a series that looks like:

```
0   1
1   2
2   4
3   4
4   4
```

And return values from another function (Which I can't modify unfortunately cause it's coming from another source) that looks like either a series like:

```
1   A
2   B
4   C
```

OR a dataframe that looks like this

```
    cola colb colc
1   A    T    F
2   B    F    F
4   C    T    T
```

I'm trying to return output that either looks like

```
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   C
4   C
```

or

```
    cola colb colc
0   A    T    F
1   B    F    F
2   C    T    T
3   C    T    T
4   C    T    T
```

depending on what type is returned by the function. I'm able to write a script that performs this iteratively, but I feel like there must be a more efficient, more pandas specific way of performing this operation, so before I generate a hideous nested monstrosity I figured I'd check if there's a well-supported way!

Comment: For the first one you can achieve this using `map` so something like `s.map(s1)` assuming `s` and `s1` are your respective series, for the second output you can do this using `merge` so something like `pd.DataFrame(s).merge(df, left_on=[col_name], right_index=True, how='left')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how your data really looks like so you may need to modify my code slightly but the following works using [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map):

```
In [32]:
s.map(s1[1])

Out[32]:
0
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    C
4    C
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

for the second one you can perform a left [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) but you have to construct a dataframe from your series:

```
In [41]:
pd.DataFrame(s).merge(df, left_on=[1], right_index=True, how='outer')

Out[41]:
   1 cola colb colc
0                  
0  1    A    T    F
1  2    B    F    F
2  4    C    T    T
3  4    C    T    T
4  4    C    T    T
```

For the above you can set the index after the merge

**EDIT**

Actually for your second problem it's easier to use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) and pass the series values:

```
In [42]:
df.reindex(s)

Out[42]:
  cola colb colc
1               
1    A    T    F
2    B    F    F
4    C    T    T
4    C    T    T
4    C    T    T
```

Comment: This definitely works, and I'm using a similar approach to get the data right now. To expand on my question, i guess what I'm really after is determining whether it's possible to take advantage of the indexes being the same and use the same function to address both cases, or if it's necessary to check the type and perform the correct operation

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.merge to do that.

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,4,4,4])
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':[1,2,4], 'colB':['A','B','C']})
pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['series']), df, left_on='series', right_on='colA')
```

Output:

```
       series  colA colB
0       1     1    A
1       2     2    B
2       4     4    C
3       4     4    C
4       4     4    C
```